# Kohana - HTTP Tests

Tags: phpunit, kohana

I have inherited an old app written in Kohana 3.3 framework. I would like to create HTTP tests which would include going to a project website, filling out forms, submitting forms, etc. How can I write such tests with PHPUnit? Can someone point me to some articles. Any input appreciated.